# Getting type of range for use in member declaration

Tags: d

I have a somewhat complex range I want to assign to a data member of a class.

```
chain(nicklist,
      map!(a=>format("%s%d", nicklist[0], a))(sequence!"n+1"()))
```

`nicklist` is just a `string[]`.  Normally my trusty friend `auto` would just take care of this but for a data member I need to declare the type and I'm at a loss for what that type should be.  I've tried to figure out how to use `typeof()` to get it but the runtime arguments confuse me and I haven't been able to figure out how to formulate it.

(this is being used for an IRC bot. nicklist is a list of nicks I want it to try in order and after it has exhausted all of those with nick collisions it'll just try the first nick with numbers appended)

Comment: +1 for using C#-style lambdas :D

Comment: Btw you can always say `pragma(msg, typeof(<FOO>));` to print out the type of the expression `<FOO>`. Might be useful.

Comment: It is not a C# style, but more generally ML-style lambda which is around for two decades... I presume C# designers were influenced by it too...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This would work:

```
typeof(chain(cast(string[])[], map!(a=>format("%s%d", "", a))(sequence!"n+1"()))) memberVar;
```

Another possibility would be to have a function wrap it and then take its return type and use that:

```
auto func(string[] nicklist)
{
    return chain(nicklist,
                 map!(a=>format("%s%d", nicklist[0], a))(sequence!"n+1"()));
}

ReturnType!func memberVar;
```

`ReturnType` is in std.traits.

Comment: Used the ResultType approach.  Worked great.  Thanks.